# How can I draw a sparkline with achartengine without a border?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I have written a simple app widget that tries to display a time chart as a sparkline using the achartengine library.
My renderer is:

```
final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multipleRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
final XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
multipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
multipleRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
multipleRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
multipleRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
multipleRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
```

and after creating a dataset I draw to a bitmap using:

```
final TimeChart tc = new TimeChart(dataset, multipleRenderer);
final Bitmap image1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(INITIAL_WIDTH, INITIAL_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image1);
tc.draw(canvas, 0, 0, INITIAL_WIDTH, INITIAL_HEIGHT);
```

but annoyingly the chart I get has a thick border where the axes and labels would have been.

I would like to know if there is a better way using achartengine of plotting my sparkline so that it occupies the whole width of the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multipleRenderer.setMargins() and multipleRenderer.setShowLegend() in order to hide the extra stuff you may not need.

Regards,

Dan

Comment: Thanks, I was using 0.5.0 and I think setMargins must have been added in 0.6.0, but that has solved the problem I was having much better than my existing hack.